# Testing one Spring Test Class for many different set of profiles

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am working with:

- Spring Framework `4.3.10`
- JUnit `4.12`
- Gradle `4.3.1`

I have these two test classes

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class})
@ActiveProfiles(resolver=TestJdbcActiveProfilesResolver.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={LoggingTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode=MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class PersonaServiceImplJdbcTest {


@Transactional
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class})
@ActiveProfiles(resolver=TestHibernateActiveProfilesResolver.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={LoggingTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode=MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class PersonaServiceImplHibernateTest {
```

The code about the `@Test` methods are the same for both Test classes, breaking the `DRY` principle, the unique difference between these two test classes is the `jdbc` and `Hibernate` profiles working together with other such as `development, mysql`, it internally through each `TestXXXActiveProfilesResolver` class variation.

Until here I have 2 test classes, breaking the `DRY` principle, thinking in hierarchy I am going to get 3.

How (if is possible) use **one** Test class where for each interaction executes two (or more) sets of profiles such as:

- `jdbc,development,mysql`
- `Hibernate,development,mysql`

I already have read:

- [Spring Boot / JUnit, run all unit-tests for multiple profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45200126/spring-boot-junit-run-all-unit-tests-for-multiple-profiles)

But I want avoid use commands either through `Maven` or `Gradle`, it to keep the control through the `TestXXXActiveProfilesResolver` classes.

Comment: If all you're after is to share the test method code, either create a delegate they both refer to, or add a common base class with the code for sharing.

Comment: I thought the same about hierarchy, but I have the following in consideration https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/

Comment: Ok, use composition instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `JUnit` **4** finally I did the following (scroll down):

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={RootApplicationContext.class})
//@ActiveProfiles() ... disable
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={LoggingTestExecutionListener.class}, mergeMode=MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public abstract class PersonaServiceImplTest {

   ...

   @Autowired
   private Environment environment;

   @Before
   public void setup(){
    logger.info("Profiles: {}", Arrays.toString(environment.getActiveProfiles()));
   }

   //@Test disable
   public void someTest(){

     assertThat(...)

   }

    @ActiveProfiles(resolver=TestJdbcActiveProfilesResolver.class)
    public static class ForJdbc extends PersonaServiceImplTest {

        public ForJdbc(Persona persona){
            super(persona);
        }

        @Test
        @Override
        @Sql(scripts={"classpath:/.../script.sql"})//when be necessary
        public void someTest()(){
            super.someTest()();
        }

      }

    @ActiveProfiles(resolver=TestHibernateActiveProfilesResolver.class)
    public static class ForHibernate extends PersonaServiceImplTest {

        public ForHibernate(Persona persona){
            super(persona);
        }

        @Test
        @Override
        @Sql(scripts={"classpath:/.../script.sql"})//when be necessary
        public void someTest()(){
            super.someTest()();
        }

        ...

      }

   }
```

**Observations**:

- The `outer class` must be `abstract`
- The `outer class` must have no `@ActiveProfiles` declared
- The `outer class` has the methods to be tested, each one must have **no**  the `@Test` declared
- `Environment` is optional but is useful to let know the profiles activated for each `static nested class`, it through the common method annotated with `@Before`
- Each `static nested class` must be `public`
- Each `static nested class` must extends the `outer class`
- Each `static nested class` must have `@ActiveProfiles`
- Each `static nested class` overrides each test method, just to use `super` to call the respective overridden method
- Each `static nested class`, for each test overridden method, it must have the `@Test`.
- `@Sql` can't be reused, it must be declared for each overridden method