# jest - run one test-module with different test setup multiple times

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, integration-testing

There is an application running on `NodeJS`. Its architecture is inspired by Oncle Bob's book: "Clean Architecture". All works perfectly, but:
At the moment we have unit-tests for all of our modules running with the fake-DB. We want to do integration-tests in that way: use the same tests (as we used for unit-tests) for integration tests but "inject" the real DB.
How could I do that with `jest`? I don't want to copy all the unit-test code and create code duplication (except for the test-setup).

The unit-tests actually look like this:

```js
const DB = require("FakeDB");
let test_description = "unit-testing with FakeDB";

describe(`${test_description}`, () => {

    let db;

    beforeAll(() => {
        const cnf = create_config("test");
        db = new DB(cnf);
    });

    afterAll( () => {
        db.connection_close();
    });

    test("should save entity to DB", () => {
        try {
            // execute: save entity to DB 
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    })
})
```

How could I inject another DB, e.g. to `require("PostgresDB")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say we have two module add.js & add_copy.js having same function.

```
function add (a, b) {
    return a + b
  }

module.exports = {add}
```

Install dotenv `npm install dotenv`

Create .evn file

```
DB=One
```

Dummy Spec file

```
let add;
if (process.env.DB == "One"){
     add = require('./add.js');
}
if (process.env.DB == "Two"){
     add = require('./add_copy.js');
}

let test_description = "unit-testing with FakeDB";

describe(`${test_description}`, () => {
    
    beforeAll(() => {
      
    });

    afterAll( () => {
        
    });

    test("some test", () => {
       console.log(add.add(2,3));

    })
})
```

jest.config.js for this example

```
require('dotenv').config();
module.exports = {
    verbose: true,
  };
```

Here 'add' is changing as per 'DB' value provided in the .evn file.

You can also try something similar

```
let MyDB;
if (process.env.DB == "Fake"){
     MyDB= require("FakeDB")
}
if (process.env.DB == "Real"){
     MyDB= require("PostgresDB")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to break out the piece of code that sets up what the tests are going to run against. Once you've done that, then you can run the tests twice: once against the fake dB and once again the real dB.

This is just off the top of my head, but it might be what you're looking for. You can probably do more to clean it up, though:

```
const FakeDB = require("FakeDB")
const RealDB = require("PostgresDB")
describe('unit testing with FakeDB', () => {
   let db;

    beforeAll(() => {
       const cnf = create_config("test");
        db = new FakeDB(cnf);
    });

    afterAll( () => {
        db.connection_close();
    });

    test("should save entity to DB", () => {
        myTest(db);
    })
})

describe('unit testing with RealDB', () => {
   let db;

    beforeAll(() => {
        const cnf = create_config("real");
        db = new RealDB(cnf);
    });

    afterAll( () => {
        db.connection_close();
    });

    test("should save entity to DB", () => {
        myTest(db);
    })
})
myTest(db) {
        try {
            // execute: save entity to DB 
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to implement your idea. I've provided a codesnippet; may you provide some code which covers your idea?

Comment: @Chris I updated my answer. Let me know if this helps example my point.

Comment: No, sorry, that solution copies each test and there are code duplications for each test. I want to avoid these duplications and I'm looking for a solution that prevents me from copiing each test.
If the code was Java code, I would come up with the following two options: 1. Create an abstract base-testclass and inject the DB in each generalization of each test class OR 2. usage of mvn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45262452/7421890.
But I do not know which possibilities or options do I have in JS?

Comment: Typescript does have the concept of abstract classes. You could use that and get closer to your goal of low code duplication.

Comment: Late answer... Many thanks! We tried a lot and came up to the result that for `Node.js` we do not like any possible solution ;)